# How to retrieve the checkbox which were selected and deselected now -Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I have a table where object records are displayed along with a checkbox. All the existing records are displayed with checkbox ticked. If the User deselects the checkbox on any of the rows I should be setting field values accordingly in the backend. Code is as follows which is able to pick up the selected rows.

```
<td scope="row" data-label="Select">
  <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="mSelected" value="true"/>
</td>
```

js controller:

```
         for( var i=0; i < component.find("mSelected").length; i++) {
        if( component.find("mSelected")[i].get("v.value") == true ){
        selectedRecs.push(dataRecs[i]);
        }    }
```

But how do we retrieve unselected rows which were selected earlier? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the old values available somewhere in order to compare what was to what is. Here's a sample algorithm to get you started. You may want to read up on some of these methods ([filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) if you haven't used them before, they're rather convenient.

```
    // Saved values from before
var oldData = component.get("v.oldData"),
    // Newly selected value mapped into an Array of Boolean
    newData = component.find("mSelected").map(v => v.get("v.value")),
    // Data rows/records
    records = component.get("v.dataRows"),
    // Squish into an object to filter by
    mapped = records.map((v, i) => { record: v, selected: newData[i] }),
    // And get the records that meet the criteria
    changed = mapped.filter((v, i) => oldData[i] && !v.selected).map(v => v.record);
    // "changed" contains records previously selected and now not.
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, will go through and improvise on this space! I found another way, I am checking if the dataRec has Id created for it. If its there and its unchecked it means User has deselected it.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the ones that have the value set to `false` by checking their value (similar to what you did, but inverse the condition). Something within the lines of:

```
    const uiArray = component.find("mSelected");
    uiArray.forEach(function(element) {
        if(!element.get("v.value")){
            //Do something
        }
    });
```

You should probably consider storing the state of your table in some kind of object/map so you can later compare checked/unchecked records.

Comment: The problem here I have is I am displaying the existing records (checked) along with few new records (unchecked) for selection. So I really need to differentiate a new record and existing rec deselection @glls

Comment: you just need to re-terate over your array,, check for those whose fvalue  is equals to false, Do something represents whatever or however you controll that which you are stating, do you have some kind of map where you are tracking this? maybe you should consider doing so? as is, you are simply asking a how-to questions.

Comment: Sure thing, I don't have hands on lightning before. I am trying to implement first time with stringent deadlines.